# Fake Interview Scenario: Hangman

Tags: c#, interview-questions, hangman

For a fake interview I decided to write Hangman. The first question I have is when reviewing someone's code for a job interview is it more important to write something short and sweet that gets the job done, or to write something using Dependency Injection and small OOP modules?

Attached is a small example I came up with that took thirty minutes or so. If you were reviewing this code would you think it is acceptable or would you expect someone, in say an hour, to produce something that shows off more skills?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Hangman
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private const string WordToGuess = "HANGMAN";
        private static readonly HashSet<char> LettersToGuess = new(WordToGuess.ToCharArray());
        private const int MaxLives = 5;

        private static readonly HashSet<char> _guessedLetters = new();

        private static void Main(string[] _)
        {
            while (!WonGame && LivesRemaining > 0)
            {
                var displayStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                displayStringBuilder
                    .AppendLine(WordDisplay)
                    .Append("Letters Guessed: ").AppendLine(GuessedLettersDisplay)
                    .Append("Lives Remaining: ").Append(LivesRemaining)
                    .AppendLine().AppendLine()
                    .Append("Enter a guess: ");

                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write(displayStringBuilder.ToString());

                var guess = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!ValidGuess(guess)) continue;

                _guessedLetters.Add(char.ToUpper(guess[0]));
            }

            var endingStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            endingStringBuilder
                .Append("The word was: ").AppendLine(WordToGuess)
                .AppendLine(WonGame ? "You Won!" : "You Lost!");

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(endingStringBuilder.ToString());
        }

        private static int LivesRemaining => MaxLives - _guessedLetters.Except(LettersToGuess).Count();
        private static bool WonGame => !LettersToGuess.Except(_guessedLetters).Any();

        private static string WordDisplay => string.Join(' ', WordToGuess.ToCharArray().Select(x => _guessedLetters.Contains(x) ? x : '_'));
        private static string GuessedLettersDisplay => string.Join(',', _guessedLetters);

        private static bool ValidGuess(string guess)
        {
            if (guess.Length != 1) return false;
            return char.IsLetter(guess[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: short answer, it depends on the recruiter and the skills that they're looking for. Some would focus on following OOP concepts, design patterns, and other standards. Others will  might focus on the knowledge and the skills on a particular field (e.g. ASP.NET, xamarin ..etc.). but in most cases, the common standards like comments, naming conversion, and other best practices to that field are always looked at.

Comment: Do you want to receive a code review? (like you have used inconsistent naming, for example `LettersToGuess`,  `_guessedLetters`) Or do you want to know is it a junior/medior/senior level? Or xyz?

Comment: Code review would be okay - the naming convention was deliberate as the _guessedLetters was the only field that actually changes.

Comment: I would say that DI is not expected for small examples (unless specifically asked for the purpose of proving you have the skill), but OOP principles are inherently expected to be showcased in C#, especially for an interview. If I were the interviewer here, I would question the absence of basic OOP implementations, but I wouldn't even have thought that this needed DI in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my observations

#### `ValidGuess`

- I would suggest to either call it `ValidateGuess` or `IsGuessValid`
- I would also suggest to use [expression bodied method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) just like you did with other members

```
private static bool IsGuessValid(string guess) => guess.Length == 1 ? char.IsLetter(guess[0]) : false;
```

- I would also suggest to invert the condition. With that form the fallback logic becomes more visible

#### `LettersToGuess`

- Your `HashSet` is not immutable. You just can't replace the entire collection but you can replace any member of the collection.
- [`System.Collections.Immutable` namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-5.0) provides several really useful structures and extension methods:

```
private static readonly ImmutableArray<char> WordToGuess = "HANGMAN".ToImmutableArray();
private static readonly ImmutableHashSet<char> LettersToGuess = WordToGuess.ToImmutableHashSet();
```

#### `WordToGuess`

- I've also suggest to store it as a character collection instead of `const`

  - In `WordDisplay` for instance you are converting the `string` over and over again to `char[]`
- In your `endingStringBuilder` you can simply convert the `ImmutableArray<char>` to `string` like this:

```
.Append("The word was: ").AppendLine(new string(WordToGuess.AsSpan()))
```

#### `displayStringBuilder`, `endingStringBuilder`

- I would suggest to avoid echoing the `StringBuilder`
- If you want to emphasize that they are builders then try to use naming like these:

  - `gameStatusInformationBuilder` or simply just `statusInformationBuilder`
  - `gameSummaryInformationBuilder` or simply just `summaryInformationBuilder`

#### `Main`

- The `Main` method can bee written [in several different ways](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#overview)
- If you are unconcerned about the `args` then simply just get rid of the parameter

```
static void Main() 
{ 
   ...
}
```

#### `MaxLives`, `LivesRemaining`

- It is minor, but using a convenient naming helps eligibility
- For example: `MaxLives` and `RemainingLives`

#### `if (!IsGuessValid(guess)) continue;`

- I think providing an informative error message here and then `continue`, might help the player to fix his/her previous issue

Answer (score 2):

> ... to produce something that shows off more skills?

Requirements + Design + Code = Art.  That's the thing.

## Design

**Does not implement of the Hangman *game*.** With only a single hardcoded word there is - by design - a one use throw-away thing, not a game.

**Manually replacing the guess-word requires a program re-write each time.** "No, only change the WordToGuess value" you say. I say tell that to the version control software; you've never had to deliver and maintain working software for a living, have you? Any change no matter how trivial requires review, testing, integration, deployment, customer requirements, and more. Therefore to change from "HANGMAN" to "EXEMPLOYEE" can never be though of as less consequential than "re-writing" code.

**Dependency Injection per se is not a design goal.** It is a consequence of thoughtful modular, if not explicit object oriented, design. Modules (per se) is not a design goal. THE overall goal is separation/independence of program functions. We call this the Single Responsibility Principle...

**The Hangman algorithm has no business directly outputting to display**. There can be differing views of nuanced functional responsibility even in Hangman game, but not this. Extracting the console display code will result in plenty of purposeful "DI" and "small modules". Don't force the buzz-word bingo BS into the code. Likely adds complexity with no justifiable benefit.

**I don't understand why the `static` class.** `Program` is THE Hangman class, why name it `Program` and make it static? Bad class names wrapped in a `Hangman` namespace are still bad class names.  Read this SO thread:  [Why is the class Program declared static?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19092394/463206). In the chosen answer quote:

> `Program`'s responsibility is to provide an entry point for the application, so it shouldn't do anything more

**This is a small program but** there is room for abstracting concepts and code, encapsulating details, etc.

**If I make any wrong assumptions** or code misreadings I get to put that on the coder too. Structure, meaningful names, abstractions, encapsulation, SOLID, idioms, judgement, etc. make even "simple" programs non-trivial.

## Coding

[Extract a method](https://qafoo.com/blog/098_extract_method.html) - too much detail for the main game loop

```
var displayStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            displayStringBuilder
                .AppendLine(WordDisplay)
                .Append("Letters Guessed: ").AppendLine(GuessedLettersDisplay)
                .Append("Lives Remaining: ").Append(LivesRemaining)
                .AppendLine().AppendLine()
                .Append("Enter a guess: ");

            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write(displayStringBuilder.ToString());
```

---

"CorrectGuess" is, well, correct. "Valid" has a broader meaning in user interaction. A letter of the alphabet is valid input, but only guess-word's letters are correct.

```
 private static bool ValidGuess(string guess)
```

Guarding for INVALID input is too weak

```
private static bool ValidGuess(string guess)
    {
        if (guess.Length != 1) return false;
        return char.IsLetter(guess[0]);
    }

// suggestions:
private static bool ValidGuess(string guess)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(guess)) return false;

        if (guess.Length != 1) return false;
        
        // IsLetter can throw NullArgumentException, but the
        // above guards for that.
        return char.IsLetter(guess[0]);
    }
```

`ValidGuess` does only that, not looking for a correct `WordToGuess` letter. Excellent example of single responsibility.

SO thread: [isNullOrWhitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6976641/463206)

I've come to appreciate short `if`s when one-lined and without braces. But always leave whitespace above & below control blocks (not just "if") no matter how long. A big bang for the buck readability tip!

---

Over engineered?  I don't get the necessity for a `HashSet`. Also, a `string` is a `char` array. In other words you can directly `forEach(letter in myString)`

```
private static readonly HashSet<char> LettersToGuess = new(WordToGuess.ToCharArray());
```

---

main game loop should read as "high level" and accurately express the conditions of play

```
while (!WonGame && LivesRemaining > 0)
```

.

Express "Am I still alive?", NOT "is lives remaining more than zero?". I don't care how many, just if any. The sooner the code abstracts away from talking to us in low level DNA bits, the better.

```
while (!WonGame && StillAlive)

protected bool StillAlive { get {return LivesRemaining > 0; }}
```

.

`!WonGame` here really means we mis-guessed the word.

```
while ( WrongGuess && StillAlive )

protected bool WrongGuess { get { ... }}
```

Now we understand the conditions for continuing the game. Without needing to read underlying code.

.

What is overall "keep going" concept here in Hangman universe?

```
while (NotHung) { ... }

protected bool NotHung { get { return WrongGuess && StillAlive; }}
```

We could argue all day about the property's negative name. It's the idea we're after.